# How to combine git history from wrong svn migration - old repository

Tags: git, svn, git-rewrite-history

We have a git repository migrated form SVN. Let's name it as WORKING. 
Due a svn copy folder operation the history was not well migrated.
The error was :

```
SVN :  r1    \ --> common folder --> Project1 \ folder1
                                                file2 
  . 
  .  some time later
  .
  . 
SVN :  r1000 \ --> Common folder
               --> Project1 \ folder1
                              file2  
                    ^
                    |
                    ------> this folder has been migrated to GIT
```

This change caused a incomplete history migration (Only appear from HEAD to r1000) 
Now we want to add that old history into WORKING (from r1000 to r1), we have created a new git repository with the missing history (let's name as OLDEST) . The history log appear as :

```
WORKING --> A (1.2018) - B (2.2018) - C (3.2018) - D (HEAD)
OLDEST --> E (1.2016) ... F (1.2017)
```

We want this log history

```
WORKING --> E ... F --> A - B - C
```

The paths are exactly the same and we want keep the history when you see the full history of a file. The test i made i was unable to mix those histories, it is possible?

### More details

I migrated the repository using :

```
URL=http://server.name/project1
git svn clone --authors-file=authors.txt $URL -r1000:HEAD first-migration
```

Some time later I have done

```
URL=http://server.name/common/
git svn clone --authors-file=authors.txt $URL -r1:1000 second_migration
cd second_migration
git filter-branch
```

Now we have two repositories. first-migration is in use and contains active development, second_migration contains the old revisions (from 1-1000)

Mi current solution is :

```
mkdir migration
cd migration
git init
git remote add newest ssh://gitserver:first-migration
git remote add older  ssh://gitserver:second-migration
git remote update 
git checkout newest/master -b new.master
git checkout 1abc2def3   -b new.firstcommit 
git checkout older/master -b old.master
git rebase --preserve-merges --root --committer-date-is-author-date new.master
git checkout new.master -b master
git remote add fullhistory ssh://gitserver:final.git
git push fullhistory --all
```

In this case new.firstcommit is the first commit i made during first migration (r1000) (as reference for documentation)

After those operations the full history is available on remote repository but the history appear disconnected

[image]

My question is about how to integrat old history in the better way.

Comment: You can only make a *new* repository that has the desired history. (Though you can do this "in place" using `git filter-branch`.) If that's OK—if it is OK to have everyone who has cloned the repo you named WORKING to throw away their clones and start over—then see any of the StackOverflow postings about grafting history via `git replace` followed by `git filter-branch`.

Comment: But my problem is how to 'mix' old history with new one. All the suggested changes appear like disconnected histories.

Comment: Presumably that's because they *are* disconnected histories. (View the commit graph, e.g., `git log --graph`, to find out for sure.) If so, the only way to fix this is to produce a new / different repository.

Comment: That is not a problem, but after create a new repository the histories keep disconnected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thans to the comment of  [alo-malbarez here](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/176496/como-combinar-el-historico-de-git-de-una-migracion-svn-erronea/180061#comment337073_176496) and [this page](http://matthew-brett.github.io/pydagogue/rebase_without_tears.html#id1) i could solve the problem. Finally I did :

```
git checkout old.master
git cherry-pick new.firstcommit
# I commit the day I merged histories. 
git commit --allow-empty -m "Mixing histories"
git rebase -s recursive -Xtheirs --onto old.master new.firstcommit new.master
git push --all --tags
```

And this solved my problem.